# Laravel/homestead installation issues

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant

I am trying to install the homestead vagrant box for developing purposes. I followed this [guide](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/homestead#installation-and-setup), but when i use `homestead init` i get this error: `'homestead' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` although i have `~/.composer/vendor/bin` added to my PATH enviroment.

Does anyone know how i can solve this problem?

Comment: And do you have `homestead` in your `~/.composer/vendor/bin` directory?

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek Yes i do, also rebooted my machine but no results

Comment: Have you tried launching it using `~/.composer/vendor/bin/homestead` ?

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek got it working, i just added the full path  to `composer/vender/bin` to the PATH enviroment. Probably a windows quirk. But thank you for your help.

Comment: `~/.composer/vendor/bin` Is unix notation for file structure, it's completely different in windows. `%USERPROFILE%/.composer/vendor/bin` if memory serves.

Comment: Sorry.. I incorrectly posted on a wrong thread. Deleted my answer below.

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek Hi, I know this is an old post. I do not have homestead in that directory? How do I add it there? This is the guide I followed: https://laravel.com/docs/master/homestead it is version 5.1 now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try downgrading to Homestead 2.0.7 - there are currently some problems with Windows path to home folder.

Edit your composer.json file in %appdata%\Composer and change your laravel/homestead dependency to:

"laravel/homestead": "2.0.7"

Then run `composer update` on the file.

That worked for me!

See the bottom of this post: http://mikesinn.com/development/how-to-install-composer-in-windows/

Answer (score 1):

add this location `C:Users/m_000/AppData/Roaming/Composer/vendor/bin.` into path window then run `homestaed init`

Comment: Better say `C:\Users\[YourUserName]\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin` as the path.